# Usabilidade de ações em grid

Tags: usabilidade

Ao falarmos em usabilidade, temos N parametros.

Ao termos registros e os mesmo podendo haver inúmeras ações.

Qual é a melhor forma para tratar essas ações?

Colocar as ações na linha do grid? com dropdown para várias ações...

Deixar os botões desacoplado do grid e fazendo-o selecionar o registro(linha) do grid e clicar sobre o botão da ação desejada?

Ou fazer com que ele vá para os detalhes do registroe lá faça todas as ações daquele registro

Levando em conta o seguinte caso:

Contas a Receber

Vejamos, eu posso:

Editar/Deletar/Imprimir boleto/enviar boleto por email/definir como recebido/ definir como não recebido

Comment: Ações comuns, já deixar o botão/link na linha do grid. E o resto, na tela detalhe [Editar] do registro.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @Tony, nem sabia se aqui era o local correto, você diz deixar na própria linha comandos básicos "Editar/Excluir" e nos Detalhes outra ações em botões fora, certo? E botões como "Novo" deixa-se em cima né? acho que fica uma boa usabilidade...

Comment: Facilitaria a obtenção de uma resposta se você especificar quais "ações" podem ser efetuadas sobre um registro (e principalmente se o usuário pode fazer apenas uma ou mais do que uma ação em um determinado registro). Com base na sua pergunta atual, poderia-se imaginar que o método de fazer "bulk" de ações para registros marcados é o ideal, mas a sua última frase ("[...] faça lá todas as ações daquele registro") dá margem pra outras possibilidades...

Comment: Editei, haverá várias ações Luiz

Answer (score 4):

A sua pergunta não está muito clara e talvez algumas imagens com as opções que você imagina tivessem sido úteis. Pra tentar ajudar eu estou considerando que no seu sistema (de Contas a Receber) você tem uma lista de registros (ou seja, boletos ou contas dispostos em uma tabela "rolável"), e que a sua dúvida é sobre a *melhor* (do ponto de vista da usabilidade) forma de permitir ao usuário aplicar as seguintes ações aos registros:

- Editar
- Deletar
- Imprimir boleto
- Enviar boleto por email
- Definir como recebido
- Definir como não recebido

Considerando que podem haver inúmeros registros que o usuário deseje deletar, imprimir ou enviar por email, parece fazer sentido permitir que ele selecione os registros desejados e execute a ação **uma única vez** (talvez por meio de um botão, como você mesmo sugeriu). Essa alternativa (em oposição a fazer com que o usuário execute a ação para cada registro) é mais eficiente, e por isso potencialmente melhor para a usabilidade. Nesse caso, como a ação é imediata (os registros são simplesmente deletados!), faz sentido também confirmar tais interações antes de executá-las (segundo também o princípio de segurança e prevenção de erros da Usabilidade).

A edição é algo que parece fazer mais sentido de ser realizada individualmente, pois enquanto edita uma conta o usuário mantém seu quadro contextual em memória (isto é, toda a sua limitada consciência está focada naquela conta). Então provavelmente faça mais sentido colocar a opção que dá acesso à essa função na linha do registro.

Talvez isso também valha para a definição da conta como recebida ou não, principalmente se é uma questão apenas de alternar (*toggle*) um campo gráfico como um *check-box*. Se, por outro lado, a definição como recebido ou não tiver consequencias importantes (por exemplo, uma vez que uma conta seja marcada como não recebida, pra ser marcada como recebida ela precisará ser devidamente processada com inserção de dados em outros sistemas - talvez um módulo fiscal?), o princípio de segurança e prevenção de erro se aplica, e nesse caso pode ser melhor tratar essa ação tal qual as ações de deletar, imprimir e enviar por email (isto é, permitindo a seleção e execução a "granel" (*in bulk*).

Deve ser fácil perceber que tem alguns "SE"s importantes nos parágrafos anteriores. O fato é que essas "dicas" são heurísticas (entenda como regras de melhores práticas) que você pode empregar pra construir e avaliar sua interface você mesmo. Aliás, se olhar para sistemas similares (registros de email são o exemplo mais clássico), verá que esses problemas são geralmente tratados de formas similares às que eu exemplifiquei.

Mas, faz muito sentido você testar protótipos com seus potenciais usuários. Assim, você vai ser capaz de entender quais objetivos de design são mais importantes para cada ação (desempenho, segurança, memorização?) e assim definir propriamente o que tratar como "melhor" no seu domínio de problema (não é a toa que eu usei itálico nessa palavra lá no primeiro parágrafo). :)