# Formas diferentes de se expor dados

Tags: html, layout

É errado expor dados e ações que deverão (inputs, e botões) ser feitas sobre estes dados em tabelas?

Exemplo na figura abaixo esta sendo exibido dados e ações que deverão (inputs, e botões) ser feitas na forma de tabela (em vermelho) assinalado com uma seta verde esta o cabeçalho e azul  o conteúdo da tabela, esta forma de exposição é correta (lembrando do *tableless*)?

[image: SS]

Comment: Não entendi, pode editar e explicar melhor a dúvida? Quer saber se deveria usar tabela ou divisão neste caso?

Comment: Sim, gostaria de saber se neste caso o uso de tabelas vai contra os padrões tableless

Comment: Não vejo problemas em ter ações dentro da tabela, mas claro, isso é questão de opinião =). No entanto, se a tabela terá poucos registros / linhas, acredito que uma forma diferente de exibir os dados seja melhor, como um `card` por exemplo. [Link](https://www.google.com.br/design/spec/components/cards.html#cards-usage)

Comment: Olá @Oeslei, bem serão algumas dezenas de dados, acho que esta quantidade inviabilizaria o uso de cards mas verei se aplico entre outros pontos (me parece bem interessante)

Comment: Olá. Eu não sei o que é o "padrão tableless", mas se eu entendi corretamente a sua pergunta é muito próxima dessa aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31286/usabilidade-de-a%C3%A7%C3%B5es-em-grid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certo ou errado é relativo. Duvido que exista uma resposta definitiva para cada caso. Tem que fazer o que é o ideal para a situação. De fato precisa de experiência para acertar cada caso, especialmente quando parece que duas soluções são viáveis, e isto é importante. O problema do uso da tabela como formatador (o que ocorria no passado) é que ela inviabilizava muita coisa, por um motivo ou outro.

À principio não veria muito problema em usar uma tabela neste caso porque você vai montar uma tabela de dados. Fica claro, principalmente pelo cabeçalho, que você tem uma tabela aí, mas você tem que se perguntar se está lidando com uma tabela de dados ou só com formatação de apresentação. Este deve ser o critério.

Se é uma tabela, parece ser, tem que ver se ela é composta por várias linhas e apenas uma coluna. Ou se ela terá várias colunas por linha. Novamente você deve se perguntar se estes dados da linha são itens separados da tabela, são células de verdade ou se eles estão separados apenas por formatação. Ter várias colunas não parece errado.

Não me agrada ter botões de ação em uma coluna. Eles não são dados. Mas não digo que esteja de todo errado. O *checkbox* também é uma ação e acho que poucas pessoas dirão que é um abuso colocá-lo na tabela.

Eu ainda acho que eles deveriam estar em outro lugar, possivelmente em uma divisão em outra camada e talvez até só aparacer quando passar o *mouse*. Mesmo que fiquem fixos eles parecem intrusos no meio dos dados. O "Status" também tem um botão mas ele não parece intruso, ele parece adequado como UI para mudar o estado do dado ali contido. O problema dos outros é que aparentam estar relacionados com toda a linha e isto precisa ser demarcado melhor.

Talvez um híbrido vá bem, como em quase tudo. Você pode usar divisões praticamente em qualquer lugar. Use tabela onde é uma tabela mas sempre que não estiver claro que um elemento é uma célula de dado, use a divisão.

Deixando claro que o uso exclusivo de divisões é perfeitamente factível também e algumas pessoas prefeririam este caminho. [Um exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14255619/table-grid-using-div-in-html-and-css). Esta solução pode dar mais poder e flexibilidade, apesar de ser ligeiramente mais complexo montar uma tabela. Considere estes pontos. O que é mais importante neste caso? Pense um pouco no futuro também.

Eu dei uma pesquisada em projetos conhecidos qual foi a escolha e as suas motivações. Parece que ninguém tem uma palavra definitiva porque optaram por usar divisões exclusivamente. Provavelmente ficam mais resguardados usando algo mais moderno e completo. Vi em muitos casos que poderiam ter usado tabela sem problemas. Ou seja, realmente não parece ter certo ou errado mas há uma preferência clara por divisões.

Claro que isto faz bastante sentido em bibliotecas que serão usados por muitos, o trabalho extra (que nem é grande) compensa. Para uma coisa rápida não sei se compensa. Mas também se fizer uma vez algo que pode ser reaproveitado outras vezes, talvez compense.

Te dei alguns subsídios, falar qual é o certo será só minha opinião.

Comment: Excelente resposta, o que me incomodava era realmente os botões dentro das colunas

Comment: Não vejo por que seja errado ter ações junto com os dados, uma vez que as ações são executadas sobre os dados das respectivas linhas. Não conhecia o termo "padrão tableless", mas pesquisando vi que se trata de evitar usar tabelas HTML para formatar conteúdo não tabular (pois se deveria usar CSS para tal). Note, entretanto, que esse *não é* o caso do AP, já que ele tem uma listagem tabular de elementos. :)

Comment: Esse não é o @LuizVieira que eu conheço, como pode não ter ouvido falar de *tableless*? :P Mas você está certo, eu provavelmente usaria tabela neste caso. Se um dia se mostrasse errado eu simplesmente mudaria. Eu certamente faria de uma forma que não seria muito traumático de mudar. Eu acho que os puristas vão dizer que ter botões lá dentro está errado, mas nunca dou bola para os puristas.

Comment: Hahaha Acontece nas melhores famílias (bom, ao menos estou feliz por ter aprendido um termo novo hoje!). Os puristas poderiam ser refutados com [critérios de usabilidade](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/31877/73) (a minha arma não-tão-secreta de costume hehehe). :)